# Ajax finish loading with prettyPhoto - jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, prettyphoto

I am opening a an ajax window using prettyPhoto: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

This is my link to open the window

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="resources/comments.php?ajax=true&width=500&height=460&projectid=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" class="buttonPro medium grey" id="commentsButton" data-projectid="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">Comments</a>
```

Inside comment.php I have a div that when its all loaded, I want it to scroll to the bottom. I have it so replying to a comment, scrolls the div to the bottom, I just cant figure out the onload of the ajax window. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example page of what you are working on?

Comment: Regardless of the page I am working on, I am just in search of the on load or oncomplete event of ajax calls in prettyphoto. The ajax demo is right here: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#ajax-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/ there is not an option for a ajax callback(). It only appears to have callbacks for changing the picture or closing prettyPhoto.

I added the ajax callback to a fork I made: https://github.com/chrisabrams/prettyphoto

Just make sure to add this:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    ajaxcallback: myfunction() {},
    //other options here
});
```

Let me know if it works and I'll pull request it to the main repo.

Comment: Ok if one doesn't exist, I can look at the source js file and maybe add one, I dont know

Comment: It should be pretty simple to add the callback to the plugin. You should definitely add it and then make a pull request to the github repo.

Comment: Well, I couldnt figure out how to do a call back but in the original source, after the ajax call I did a `$("#commentsWindow").animate({ scrollTop:9999999 }, 300);` and that worked. I wouldn't normally do 99999 but `$("#commentsWindow").props("scrollHeight")` kept returning 0

Comment: I added the ajax call if you want to just put your code in it.

Comment: let me give that a try, be back in a few

Comment: alright, I have the callback working, however, `$("#commentsWindow").prop("scrollHeight")` is still returning 0. Its like the callback is happening before the content is added and visible. This is my code i'm using: http://pastie.org/3508089

Comment: Ok I added a timeout of 300ms to the call and it now doesn't return 0: http://pastie.org/3508122

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing there is just this very small window where the content is still being applied to the page while the callback is hit.

Comment: yep..well thank you for adding the call back, that helped a bunch

Comment: Ok I see what is happening; all right I moved the callback - try now :) I updated my repo